# Install php extension on wampserver 3

Tags: php, encryption, wamp64

I would like to install the php_bolt extension in php in order to encode my souces.
I have placed my `php_bolt.dll` file in the php extensions folder.
In my `php.ini` file I add the line `extension=php_bolt.dll`.
the extension is still not loaded. And I do not know why.
In command line I have the following error

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_bolt.dll' (tried: G: /wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.25/ext/php_bolt.dll
(The specified module could not be found.), G:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.25/ext/php_php_bolt.dll.dll
(The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Did you download the right version, did you place it in the right directory of your php version and did you config the right php.ini. Wamp has multiple php.ini files and in Wamp3 extentions in php.ini are writen like this `extension=curl`. In your bin/apache/apache_version/bin folder is also a symlink to the php.ini file your apache server is using. Addind extentions in wamp has give me alot of headache some times

Comment: I would say yes.
I have already made this config in all versions of php installed in wampserver.
To be sure to configure the right file, I proceeded as follow:
<Icon Wamp> ---> PHP ---> php.ini